# What is the "Views" log data in the Rails logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a little confused about the "Views" data. In particular because I'm using Rails as an API and it is not rendering any views... but only json. So what's the deal with these numbers?

`Completed 200 OK in 240ms (Views: 135.1ms | ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using Rails as an API, it logs what it renders as a "view". Just like you can render different types of files (`html`, `js`, `xml`), but you don't visually see all of them. How this translates to using it as an API, I'm not sure, but I would expect it to be very similar.